# I cannot start OVSMU

Tags: opshub

I installed OVSMU and found the installed product in the Program Files directory and a new service installed which I started. There are many exe and bat files in a number of subdirectories but I could not figure out which is the one to run the application.

Comment: You can edit your question to fix your typos. You shouldn't post a comment for that.

Answer (score 0):

Run `C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility\ovsmu.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you install the OVSMU and after successful installation, OVSMU starts automatically.But after successful installation , you can start the OVSMU from the shortcut which might be created on your desktop or even you search "OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility" from Start menu and run the OVSMU.

As well as you can start the ovsmu.exe which is located at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility path.

Hope this will help you. If you still can not find or run the OVSMU, please let us know.